# NS_ENUM, NS_OPTIONS, NSArray[dereferencing] not working XCode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6

I'm trying to compile the [PSTCollectionView](https://github.com/steipete/PSTCollectionView) library using XCode 4.6, but for some reason, I'm getting a ton of compiler errors.  They're all centered around the newer features of Objective-C.

A few examples:

[image: NS_ENUM Undefined]

[image: NSArray dereference not working]

However, the new array/dictionary/NSNumber macros *are* defined:

[image: NSArray creation macro is defined]

I'm using the Apple LLVM Compiler

[image: Compiler]

I'm a bit stumped by this... any notions?

Comment: Which compiler is setup for your project. Make sure it is the Apple LLVM Compiler and not GCC.

Comment: Added compiler info, using Apple LLVM compiler

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently an issue caused by using the wrong SDK.  I was using the iOS 5.1 SDK, which does not allow the use of these handy new shortcuts that Apple added.  When I change to the iOS 6.1 SDK, it no longer complains about that usage.

Apple lets you know in [this article here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/index.html)